# How to convert and send HD video via SMS?

Tags: mms, video-recording

I am running stock Android 4.3 and when I use the stock Camera app and record video the file size is huge. The Camera app also has a Record for MMS option that works well but this means I don't have a HD copy of the original footage.

What I would like to do is to record some footage using the stock HD Record mode and then have a "Convert for MMS and send" button.

Is there an app or process that will help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient solution. 
It is baffling that this functionality still isn't present on stock Android.

You could use this [Video Converter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=roman10.media.converter&hl=en/) app to convert your HD videos.

Answer (score 1):

There are some applications available in Google play store.
Take a look at [SMS MMS Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alex.mms.com.android.mms).

Comment: Why?  Nothing in its description seems applicable to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like ffmpeg in command line with a terminal to re encode the video to your liking before sending it.

Comment: That's a good recommendation. Now imagine you've never used ffmpeg or any command-line program. I'm sure you can think of a way to expand your answer to be more helpful to such a visitor.